# JSDoc: @callback with @property?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I am using JSDoc and have the following definition for `Stream<T>`:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @callback Stream
 *
 * @param {T} [value]
 *
 * @return {T} the value
 */
```

This correctly translates to the following definition in `index.d.ts`:

```js
export type Stream<T> = (value?: T) => T;
```

However, a `Stream` is a function that also has a `map` property. `map` is a function that creates another stream:

```js
const s = stream(); // s is a Stream
s(5); // s is a function
// but s.map is also a function
const s2 = s.map(x => x + 1);
```

How do I define `Stream<T>` with JSDoc? The following does not work:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @callback Stream
 *
 * @param {T} [value]
 * @property {Function} map
 *
 * @return {T} the value
 */
```

That does not generate `map` and worse, loses the fact that the function returns `T`:

```js
export type Stream<T> = (value?: T) => any;
```

Ideally I would want this (or equivalent) to be generated:

```js
export interface Stream<T> {
  (value?: T) => T;
  map<U>(fn: (value: T) => U): Stream<U>;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with JSDoc?